# How to extract calling graph to specific function in Angular (or in Typescript in general)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies

I has a component A in Angular 7. Chain of calling as below:
component A --> service B.f() --> service C.f() --> service D.f() --> service E.f()

I have about 100 components like component A in the project; How can I find all component that indirectly call service E.f()? (.i.e is there any tool to extract calling graph to particular function in Angular or Typescript?)

I've found that there is plug to visualize Angular module (https://github.com/compodoc/ngd) but it seem not detail enough (.i.e specific to particular function in service or component...)

Comment: you can set a breakpoint in E.f method and use the call stack of chrome-dev-tools

Comment: Thanks but I want to static analyze not runtime debug